# Align text on the right side of multiple images

Tags: html, css

I want to align the text on the right side of images. Below I pasted code of HTML and CSS. I am also pasting fiddle for that. Please find the link for fiddle also and let me know the solution. Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/yt4cxvLs/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.img {
    margin: 50px;

   float: left;
    width: 180px;
}   


div.img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
    <img src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg">
    <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_lights.jpg">
    <img src="img_lights.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
  <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
    <img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: text description should be over image or under image?

Comment: should be on the right side of image. Neither over nor under.

Comment: well, that's the problem, because You define for container div (class called `.img`) `width:180px` and for image 'width:100%`, aaand in image tag You define image size, again.

Comment: if possible can you can correct it?

Comment: I am sorry I am confused. I took this code from w3 schools. I was looking for alignment of images and texts. At last I got that!

Comment: should text, on right side of image, need to be veritcal centered or not?

Comment: I need to make "meet the team page". So it doesn't matter at all vertical and centered.

Comment: just put in every class `float:left;`, for `.img img` remove `width` and `height`, in `.img` remove `width:180px;` or use `min-width:180px;`... that's for start but will be, well, not very nice... and, of course, before closing tag with class `img` add one more `div` with `style="clear:both;"`.

Comment: if I would do remove width and height for .img img the image size would be too large. I need to show the passport size image.

Comment: I am sorry but Its not working even with the large size of image

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer, as you can see, i just added "style=float" attribute in div element and separated </div> tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.img {
margin: 50px;

float: left;
width: 180px;
}   


div.img img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

div.desc {
padding: 15px;
text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="img">
<a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
<img src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
</a></div>
<div class="desc" style="float: right">Add a description of the image          here</div>

<div class="img">
<a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg">
<img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
</a></div>
<div class="desc" style="float: right">Add a description of the image  here</div>


<div class="img">
<a target="_blank" href="img_lights.jpg">
<img src="img_lights.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
</a></div>
<div class="desc" style="float: right">Add a description of the image here</div>


<div class="img">
<a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
<img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
</a></div>
<div class="desc" style="float: right">Add a description of the image here</div>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to align two images horizontally and also text on the right side of each.

Comment: ````style="float"```` is not a valid style.  Something like ````style="float: left"```` would be...

Answer (score 0):

So the logic is -

1. Use a `div` as a parent container and place `a` and `span` for the text inside it
2. Make parent `div`, `a` and `span` as `float:left'`

```css
.row {
 float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.row a {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.row span {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150">
  </a>
  <span>This is sample text</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150">
  </a>
  <span>This is sample text</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150">
  </a>
  <span>This is sample text</span>
</div>
```